# How do I tell what security issues require upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, security, 4.6.11

Just upgraded a site to 4.6.11 (long story as to why).

CiviCRM is showing the "Security update required", which links to https://civicrm.org/advisory

As I click on advisory after advisory, in reverse chronological order starting from "CIVI-SA-2015-011: REFLECTED XSS IN ERROR MESSAGE", *all* have been fixed prior to 4.6.11.

So ... what is the vulnerability then, if I don't upgrade to 4.7.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the advisory will be posted any moment, but you should be able to go to 4.6.12 instead of jumping to 4.7. I believe the 4.6.x branch is now a LTS branch so you don't need to go to 4.7 immediately.

**Update:** The advisories have been updated (shortly after I posted) and also an email has been sent to the security list ([subscribe here](https://civicrm.org/receive-security-advisories)):

> This is a notification of a security release for CiviCRM. We recommend
> you immediately upgrade to a secure version of CiviCRM.
>
> The most recent releases are CiviCRM 4.7.1 or CiviCRM 4.6.12. 4.4.21
> LTS has been released also.
>
> Some fixes affecting security were included in CiviCRM 4.6.10 and
> 4.6.11, but the email announcements which should accompany such releases was omitted. So, we're releasing 4.6.12 to time with a
> security release window and ensure subscribers get notified.
>
> Read the security advisories for details of the various fixes included
> in the latest CiviCRM builds:
>
> - https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2015-010-version-information-disclosure
> - https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2015-011-reflected-xss-in-error-message
> - https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2016-01-path-disclosure
> - https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2016-02-access-bypass
> - https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2016-03-multiple-vulnerabilties-in-dompdf
>
> A number of other non-security issues have also been fixed in the
> latest releases. Upgrade now for the most stable CiviCRM experience.
>
> CiviCRM security announcements are available from
> https://civicrm.org/advisory and via the CiviCRM Security
> Notifications email list.
>
> CiviCRM.org, San Francisco, CA 94117 United States